# handle API conection error with UI feedback

Tags: flutter, try-catch

I'm trying to handle and error by internet conection in an api call...
I know how to implement try/catch block, but I don't know how to use "catch" to give a UI feedback messagge to user

this is what I`ve:

```
API CALL METHOD 
this is located in another file


 getInfoWeatherLocation(String coords) async {
    apiParams() {
      return {
        'key': _key,
        'q': coords,
        'aqi': _aqi,
        'lang': (!isEnglish) ? 'es' : 'en',
        'days': _days
      };
    }

    try {
      final uri = Uri.https(_baseUrl, 'v1/forecast.json', apiParams());

      final resp = await http.get(uri);

      if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
        final weatherResp = weatherResponseFromJson(resp.body);

        location = weatherResp.location;
        current = weatherResp.current;

        forecast = weatherResp.forecast.forecastday;

        return isData = true;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return isData = false;
    }
  }

THIS METHOD IS CALLED IN OTHER PAGE INSIDE A STFULL WIDGET.

_superSearch info is called first on initState method to give  local coords and then pass it as argument to getInfoWeatherLocation

 Future _superSearchInfo() async {
    final actualLocationCoords = await geolocatorService!.getCurrentLocation();
    final searhCityCoords = weatherServ!.coords;
    final coords =
        (!newsServ!.activeSearch) ? actualLocationCoords : searhCityCoords;



i already have a try/catch inside getInfoWeatherLocation Method.
but i´ve other here, i dont know if this is well implemented.

    try {
      final hasData = await weatherServ!.getInfoWeatherLocation(coords);
      return hasData;
    } on SocketException {
      throw Exception('No internet connection');
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('An error occurred: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('NEW DESIGN PAGE BUILD');

    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _superSearchInfo(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return NoDataPage(
              icon: Icon(Icons.nat),
              text: 'Error: ${snapshot.error}',
            );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularIndicator();
          } else {
            return _WeatherWidget();
          }
        });
  }


_superSearch info is calle first on initState method to give  local coords and then pass it as argument to getInfoWeatherLocation
```

what i need is to trigger something like a Alert Dialog to notify the error on the internet conection... I don't know how to relate the catch with the method that triggers the alertDialog... i´m stuck with this :(

I'm trying to handle and error by internet conection in an api call...
i know how to implement try/catch block, but i don't know how to use "catch" to give an UI feedback messagge to user

this is what i've:

```
API CALL METHOD 


 getInfoWeatherLocation(String coords) async {
    apiParams() {
      return {
        'key': _key,
        'q': coords,
        'aqi': _aqi,
        'lang': (!isEnglish) ? 'es' : 'en',
        'days': _days
      };
    }

    try {
      final uri = Uri.https(_baseUrl, 'v1/forecast.json', apiParams());

      final resp = await http.get(uri);

      if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
        final weatherResp = weatherResponseFromJson(resp.body);

        location = weatherResp.location;
        current = weatherResp.current;

        forecast = weatherResp.forecast.forecastday;

        return isData = true;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return isData = false;
    }
  }

THIS METHOD IS CALLED IN OTHER PAGE 

 Future _superSearchInfo() async {
    final actualLocationCoords = await geolocatorService!.getCurrentLocation();
    final searhCityCoords = weatherServ!.coords;
    final coords =
        (!newsServ!.activeSearch) ? actualLocationCoords : searhCityCoords;



i already have a try/catch inside getInfoWeatherLocation Method.
    try {
      final hasData = await weatherServ!.getInfoWeatherLocation(coords);
      return hasData;
    } on SocketException {
      throw Exception('No internet connection');
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('An error occurred: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('NEW DESIGN PAGE BUILD');

    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _superSearchInfo(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return NoDataPage(
              icon: Icon(Icons.nat),
              text: 'Error: ${snapshot.error}',
            );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularIndicator();
          } else {
            return _WeatherWidget();
          }
        });
  }


_superSearch info is calle first on initState method to give  local coords and then pass it as argument to getInfoWeatherLocation
```

what i need is to trigger something like a Alert Dialog to notify the error on the internet conection... I don't know how to relate the catch with the method that triggers the alertDialog... i´m stuck with this :(

Comment: I think you'd like using FlutterBloc.  It helps you with separating UI and business logic which you are trying to do.  When network errors happen you can update a bloc's state and in the UI you can listen for bloc changes and display a snackbar or dialog to let the user know that something went wrong.

Comment: actually im using provider on my project i think is possible to do the same with it, right?